# pdflatex embed font names

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I have been using some embedded fonts (AMS, Times) in my PDF document. Last time when I browsed the document in PDF Viewer (Evince, in that particular case) I noticed that most of embedded fonts were marked as *"Noname"* in the *"Document properties"* dialog.

Although it doesn't bring any problems with browsing and printing, I wonder if there is a way to tell `pdfLatex` to include embedded fonts real names?

[image: Properties Window]

Comment: What does the picture mean? I believe most of us can't understand or read Russian.

Comment: It seems you are using bitmap fonts which pdftex converts on the fly to Type3 fonts before embedding them into PDF files, using outline (Type1) fonts would eliminate this.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel The picture says a bunch of fonts called "Noname" in the "Document properties" dialog window.

Comment: @Denis If you have solved your problem, please share the knowledge. Otherwise, try providing a minimal example of a document that exhibits the issue.

Comment: @KhaledHosny: Please convert that comment into an answer.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: but it is not an answer, a real answer would tell how to use Type1 fonts, but the question is incomplete…